# JMapper configuration issue in XML when using multiple properties in "to" argument

Tags: java, mapping

I am trying to use JMapper to map from StaticS to StaticD class. The following is the configuration.

```
<jmapper>
  <class name="com.StaticD">
    <global>
       <value name="map"/>
    </global>
  </class>
  <class name="com.StaticS">
    <conversion name="toDate" from="map" to="startDate, endDate">
        return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse((String)${source}.get("${destination.name}"));
    </conversion>
    <conversion name="toString" from="map" to="securityName, id">
        return (${destination.type}) ${source}.get("${destination.name}");
    </conversion>
  </class>
</jmapper>
```

The classes are as follows:

```
public class StaticS {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    public Map<String, String> getMap()
    {
        return map;
    }

    public StaticS(Map<String, String> map) {
        super();
        this.map = map;
    }
}


public class StaticD {

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

    private String id;

    private String securityName;

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSecurityName() {
        return securityName;
    }
    public void setSecurityName(String securityName) {
        this.securityName = securityName;
    }
    public StaticD() {}
}
```

The way I am calling mapper framework to map these two files is:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", "JMapper Framework v.1.2.0");
        map.put("endDate", "22/08/1988");
        map.put("startDate", "22/08/1987");
        map.put("securityName", "IBM");

        // ANNOTATION
        JMapper<StaticD, StaticS> mapper = new JMapper<StaticD, StaticS>(StaticD.class, StaticS.class, "staticConversion.xml");
        StaticD destination = mapper.getDestination(new StaticS(map));
        System.out.println(destination);
```

The *actual* output is as follows:

```
StaticD{id=JMapper Framework v.1.2.0, startDate=Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 1987, endDate=Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 1987, securityName=JMapper Framework v.1.2.0}
```

The *expected* output is as follows:

```
StaticD{id=JMapper Framework v.1.2.0, startDate=Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 1987, endDate=Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 1988, securityName=IBM}
```

As you can see the startDate is going to both start and endDate properties in the StaticD class in the actual output.

If I use separate conversions for each property, it is working, but, the mapping is not working when I use the same conversion for two different properties.

For instance, the following works, *but the code is redundant*.

```
<conversion name="toString" from="map" to="securityName">
            return (${destination.type}) ${source}.get("${destination.name}");
        </conversion>
<conversion name="toString" from="map" to="id">
            return (${destination.type}) ${source}.get("${destination.name}");
        </conversion>
```

*Could you suggest why the aforementioned configuration for mapping these two classes doesn't work if I use multiple properties in the to arguments?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify type="DYNAMIC" in the xml file while doing the conversion.

```
<conversion name="toDate" from="map" to="startDate, endDate" type="DYNAMIC">
        return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse((String)${source}.get("${destination.name}"));
    </conversion>
```